# How filter is working with softlayer API in python

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was trying to fetch the `storageID` through the softlayer API using filter. But it is giving me list of all storages even if i applied filter with method.

```
import SoftLayer

import json

storagename = "ABC-123"

client = SoftLayer.Client()

accountservice = client['SoftLayer_Account']

objectFilterstorage = {"username": {"operation": storagename}}

storageId = accountservice.getNetworkStorage(filter=objectFilterstorage)

print storageId
```

Also, how can we figure out which attributes are needed while fetching the list of the particular offering?

Here I found attributes & took list into 'objectFilterstorage'. But I still confused how it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following python script:

```
"""
This script retrieves storage identifier through name

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Define username name from the storage
storageUsername = 'SL345234'

# Declaring the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
# Define an object mask to get additional information from servers
objectFilter = {"networkStorage": {"username": {"operation": storageUsername}}}

try:
    storageResult = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkStorage(filter=objectFilter)
    for storage in storageResult:
        print("Storage Id: %s" % storage['id'])

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print(('Error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString)))
```

Also, I can recommend to review the below links to get a clear idea how objectFilters works:

- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)
- [Going Further with the SoftLayer API Python Client - Part
  1](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-1)
- [Going Further with the SoftLayer API Python Client - Part
  2](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-2)

I hope it helps, please let me know any doubt or comments about it